# select min and max value of a column and corresponding date (another column)

Tags: pervasive-sql

I am trying to get the lowest cost for a part and the highest cost for a part. along with the dates that they occurred. I almost have what I want except that in my query I don't know how to associate the lowest cost with the correct date. I understand why (because that's what I told the query to do) but I am wondering how can I alter the query so that when the lowest cost is selected, it selects the corresponding date as well?

Data set example:

```
|Part  |    cost   |date_received|
|------|-----------|-------------|
|846060| 28.373265 |   1/5/2022  |
|846060| 29.143835 |   2/28/2022 |
|846060| 27.588483 |   3/8/2022  |
|846060| 29.143835 |   4/25/2022 |
```

Desired output:

```
|Part  |lowest_cost|date_received|highest_cost|last_date_received|difference|
|------|-----------|-------------|------------|------------------|----------|
|846060| 27.588483 |  3/8/2022   | 29.143835  |  4/25/2022       | 1.555405 |
```

current output:

```
|Part  |lowest_cost|date_received|highest_cost|last_date_received|difference|
|------|-----------|-------------|------------|------------------|----------|
|846060| 27.588483 |  1/5/2022   | 29.143835  |  4/25/2022       | 1.555405 |
```

query I have currently:

```
select part,min(cost) as Lowest_Cost,max(cost) as Highest_Cost, 
  min(date_received) as First_date, 
  max(date_received) as Last_Date, (max(cost) - min(cost)) as Difference
from v_po_history 
where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS' and part = '846060'
group by part
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select g.part, min_cost, (select min(p1.date_received) from v_po_history p1 where p1.part = g.part and p1.cost = g.min_cost and part not like '*%' and DATE_RECEIVED >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS') as min_cost_date, 
max_cost, (select max(p2.date_received) from v_po_history p2 where p2.part = g.part and p2.cost = g.max_cost and part not like '*%' and DATE_RECEIVED >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS') as max_cost_date 
from (select part, min(cost) min_cost, max(cost) max_cost from v_po_history 
    where part not like '*%' and DATE_RECEIVED >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS'
    group by part) g
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first attempt at it but it seems to work based on your data.  I make no guarantees on performance on a larger data set.  There may be other better ways too.

```
select distinct part, description, location, t_fd.First_Date, t_fd.lowest_cost, t_ld.Last_Date, t_ld.highest_cost from
v_po_history, 
--date for lowest cost
(select top 1 date_received as First_Date, min(cost) as lowest_cost from v_po_history where 
cost = (select min(cost) from v_po_history where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS' 
and part = '846060') group by date_received) as t_fd,
-- date for highest cost
(select top 1 date_received Last_Date, max(cost) as highest_cost from v_po_history where 
cost = (select max(cost) from v_po_history where part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' and location = 'HS' 
and part = '846060') group by date_received) as t_ld
where 
part not like '*%' and date_received >= '2022-01-01' and date_received <= '2022-05-01' 
and location = 'HS' and part = '846060'
```

Comment: we're like 99% there. The last_date isn't actually grabbing the last date that the highest cost was recorded. In my data example, the highest was 29.1238 on 2/28/22 and 4/25/22. This query returns the last_date as 2/28/22. I'm playing around with it now but is there a way to get the true last_date, if it exists?

Comment: What version of Pervasive are you using?  I'm using 11.30 and the query returned 4/25/22.

Comment: we are using v 13.30

Comment: Here is a DB fiddle. I can't select pervasive as a db engine in the fiddle but in my pervasive control center I get the same results
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=121c242beea81894cb5488b7918068bd

Comment: Order is not guaranteed unless you explicitly sort.  Adding an Order By clause on the Date for highest cost (and lowest cost) sub query after the group by should resolve the order issue.

Comment: that works great when the part is hard coded. Now the guy asking for this report doesn't want to input a part number and just wants it to return for all parts. would I need a completely different query or are there any adjustments I can make to this for it to work with all parts?